# PCB pancake slip ring brushes

Tags: pcb, components, servo, robotics, electro-mechanical

I am designing a mechanical attitude indicator for the avionics simulator. I need a pancake slip ring, that drives servo (max 500mA at 5V) and some backlight.
My idea is to use a gold-plated PCB and brushes mounted on the other PCB.
But I am struggling heavily, to find suitable brushes, that can be PCB-mounted.
The only thing I found is EMI gold finger contacts and pogo-pins, but they are too stiff for this application, what I am looking for is similar to the wiper of the potentiometer. Any help?

Comment: Why can't you use a pancake slip ring?

Comment: You'll find potentiometer style wipers ... in a potentiometer. For prototyping, pull one apart and keep moving. You can also buy beryllium copper spring wire or strip by the metre.

Answer (score 1):

To build:-

[image: slip ring]

*From https://www.moflon.com/mpcb.html*

So I suggest either buy some [carbon brushes](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Electric-Motor-Power-Carbon-13-5mm/dp/B008IEV5Y0/ref=sr_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=Electrical%20Carbon%20Brushes) and mount them yourself in a DIY holder thingie, or buy a full a cheepo slip ring like the [Adafruit one](https://cpc.farnell.com/adafruit-industries/736/slip-ring-with-flange-22mm-dia/dp/MC02065).

Notice that the slip ring picture above uses four sets of brushes to maintain electrical connectivity and mitigate contact bounce.

Comment: I am planing to utilize slip-ring PCB for other electronics like connectors, drivers, etc. Adafruit one is not a pancake, so I cant drive shaft trough, low profile is also reqirement. I can google, and I did sufficient research before asking. Thank you for pointing out, that I should use multiple of something, I cant get at the first place.